# How to get the last key pressed in nativescript SearchBar?

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I want to know what is the last keystroke in SeachBar (and check whether it is a backspace specifically).

Can it be done using searchBarTextChanged(args) event?

I'm using Angular and looking for a solution for both Android and iOS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `<SearchBar (textChange)="search(searchBar.text)">` in the view, and something like this in the component:

```
search(term?: string): void {
  // reduce your list based on the search term
}
```

I'm not detecting the backspace as I'm always reducing the list (that the search term is applied to) based on the input. So if previously a term has been entered and backspace was pressed, the term would now be `''` which means the entire list can be shown.

Comment: Hi Eddy, I have a very similar scenario, and I want to recognize that the user hit backspace so I can reduce the list and not to perform a new server request. The search term is not '' in this case, but the previous string with one char less (as deleting one char and clearing the whole input are not the same). Is the only solution to compare the new term with the prevous term? No way to know what specific char was pressed?

Comment: To my knowledge you can't know what key was pressed (unless digging into native code), but indeed, a simple local string compare (old vs new) should fix that.

Comment: This is what I ended up with. Thank you!